# Load nested data to tabulator table from ajax request

Tags: javascript, json, datatables, tabulator

I have a api from a store. I take back with json request a structure like this 3 records in first level

**data, error_no, msg**

In second level inside **data** have

**data.items, data.total_pages, data.total_results**

Inside data.items (3 level) have the records who i need load to tabulator table.
So this nested records i need extract and load items only to table ? How can select them ?

[image]

```
function loadTableTab(tableData) {
    var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
        data:tableData, //set initial table data
        columns:[
            {title:"product_title", field:"product_title"},
            {title:"sale_price", field:"sale_price"},
        ],
    });
}
```

Comment: can you show the value you passed to `tableData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ***ajaxResponse*** callback to format the data in a way that Tabulator can handle, it is passed in the response and should return the array of table data, so in your case it should be:

```
function loadTableTab(tableData) {
    var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
        data:tableData, //set initial table data
        ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
            return response.data.items; // return the array of table items
        },
        columns:[
            {title:"product_title", field:"product_title"},
            {title:"sale_price", field:"sale_price"},
        ],
    });
}
```